# Turtlebot3 doesn't move in a straight line while sending goals to Nav_stack!

Tags: ros, navigation, simulation, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone! while using the code that sends goals to the navigation stack from this Link: https://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutor..., and using a simulated turtlebot3. Namely, the robot doesn't move in a straight line, it sometimes gets stuck and even stops before reaching its destination, although there is nothing where it could get stuck!. I've seen this happen using a real Turtlebot3, but I never thought it would happen in a simulation! i have thought about it a lot and don't know if it's because of the Odometry Wheels or the Lidar or the Recovery behavior...!! Any ideas!? I would greatly appreciate any possible explanations and maybe some solutions. Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399604/turtlebot3-doesn%27t-move-in-a-straight-line-while-sending-goals-to-nav_stack!/) by [Belghiti](https://answers.ros.org/users/99615/belghiti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2022-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

so hi again,

After trying to understand how odometry works and also going through many suggested solutions to improve wheel odometry on various forums, like the one from Sr. Robotics Engineer Achille Verheye in his excellent and detailed article [www.freedomrobotics.com/blog/tuning-odometry-for-wheeled-robots]: “Deploying on Mars : rock solid odometry for wheeled robots", i decided that the appropriate way for my case would be to perform the tuning of some ROS parameters as suggested on Turtlebot Navigation Tuning Guide [ https://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide ],  including robot acceleration, recovery behavior, goal tolerance parameters, the simulation time and above all the inflation radius and the cost scalling factor.
The Results were 90% of the time satisfying and i could run the Tests i wanted to.

---

Originally posted by [Belghiti](https://answers.ros.org/users/99615/belghiti/) with karma: 50 on 2022-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0